# Populate Defined Named Range with multi-element array of multi-element arrays

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, multidimensional-array

I have defined 5 arrays.

One with undefined dimensions to store the other 4:

```
Dim outputArr() As Variant
```

and the rest as follows:

```
Dim Arr1(5, 0), Arr2(12, 0), Arr3(5, 0), Arr4(12, 0) As Variant
```

I assign the elements of the latter as follows:

```
Arr1(0, 0) = [{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}]
Arr1(1, 0) = [{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}]
Arr1(2, 0) = [{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}]
Arr1(3, 0) = [{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}]
Arr1(4, 0) = [{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}]
Arr1(5, 0) = [{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}]
```

*The above is applied to each array.*

When I use

`ReDim outputArray(3, 0)`

`outputArr = [{Arr1, Arr2, Arr3, Arr4}]`

I get a `'Type Mismatch'` error.

When I do not use `Evaluate` and assign without `ReDim`

`outputArr = Array(Arr1, Arr2, Arr3, Arr4)`

I can see the elements and their values in the *Watch window*, but when I try to  populate Defined Named Ranges with the elements of `outputArr`  I get an empty output

```
Range("nRange1name").Value = outputArr(0)
Range("nRange2name").Value = outputArr(1)
Range("nRange3name").Value = outputArr(2)
Range("nRange4name").Value = outputArr(3)
```

How can I work around this?

Comment: "I get an error." - *what is the error you get*?

Comment: @TimWilliams *Type Mismatch error*.

Comment: Any ideas @TimWilliams?

Comment: Let's see the full code.

Comment: @RyanWildry, I am afraid this is it. The only things that I have left out are the assignments of the other 3 arrays `Arr2, Arr3, Arr4` and a pretty lengthy Select Case that adds values to the array elements, before I assign them to the parent array `outputArr`.

Comment: I think that the main issue is to assign the *child* arrays to the *parent* array in a way that will return a multi-dimensional array of multi-dimensional arrays. How can I achieve this?

Comment: This syntax 'Arr1(0, 0) = [{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}]' does not exist in VBA for populating arrays.  Please make sure that you have put option explicit at the start of your module and then do a 'Debug.Compile Project'so that VBA will highlight your syntax errors.

Comment: What are the dimensions of `Range("nRange1name")`?  I don't think you can do what you seem to want to do except by using an actual 2-D array: you cannot mimic that using an array of arrays.

Comment: @Freeflow, the arrays take the assigned values and even change them correctly with `Arr1(1,0)(1) = Arr1(1,0)(1) + 1`.

Comment: @TimWilliams, the dimensions are *6 rows, 12 columns*.

Comment: @TimWilliams, `Set nRange1 = .Range(.Cells(19, 3), .Cells(24, 14))
            wsTarget.Names.Add Name:="nRange1name", RefersTo:=nRange1` in a `With` block.

Comment: @I.Я.Newb  I checked, and your syntax works only when there is a Reference to Excel.  This is a new one on me!

Comment: @TimWilliams, I tried populating the `Range of Cells` without the DNR, however, I still got an empty output. And yes, you are correct - it throws a *Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed* error with the DNR.

Comment: @Freeflow, glad I helped.

Comment: @TimWilliams, How would you suggest to form an actual 2D array with the above information? Have in mind that I've tried to populate the ranges of cells with Arr1,Arr2,Arr3,Arr4 - still I get an empty output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of variants in the OP code introduces unecessary dimensions.  I don't understand why two transpose functions are needed but the following code pastes 2d arrays satisfactorily.

Option Explicit

```
Sub TestArrays()

Dim outputArr               As Variant
Dim Arr1                    As Variant
Dim Arr2                    As Variant
Dim Arr3                    As Variant
Dim Arr4                    As Variant

Arr1 = Array(Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))
Arr2 = Array(Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))
Arr3 = Array(Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))
Arr4 = Array(Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))

outputArr = Array(Arr1, Arr2, Arr3, Arr4)
' For Horizontal ranges
Range("A1:H2") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(outputArr(2)))


'For Vertical ranges
Range("A4:B11") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(outputArr(3))

End Sub
```

Comment: I will test out this approach in the morning.

Answer (score 1):

You need to construct an actual 2D array to do something like that.

```
Dim arr(1 to 6, 1 to 12)
dim r as long, c as long

for r = lbound(arr, 1) to ubound(arr, 1)
    for c = lbound(arr, 2) to ubound(arr, 2)
        arr(r, c) = 0
    next c
next r

Range("A1").Resize(ubound(arr, 1), ubound(arr, 2)).value = arr
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try your approach.
However, I am doing my best not to go to loops for that, because the database where the data for the elements comes from is pretty big. 
I used a `Select Case` for the purpose, as I do not have rights to use `Dictionaries` not to mention `FSO` on my corporate Excel account.

Comment: I never worry about performance unless it proves to be poor.  The obvious way is typically the best way, and only occasionally will you ever need to come back and re-work something.  EDIT: clearly "obvious" is subjective and I realize different people will take different approaches...

Comment: I will try this in the morning.

Comment: thank you for the time and effort spent on my question. However, Freeflow provided a simpler, yet efficient solution. Assigning elements to a 2D array with loop is like looping trough all the cells that I need to be populated. This is what I was avoiding the whole time, as performance was the reason this project was returned to our team in the first place.

Comment: Your choice, but want to point out that looping over an array is *not* comparable in performance to looping over a range cell by cell.  If you need confirmation of that I’d urge you to test it for yourself.